# How to draw Pie chart manually in Android?

Tags: android

I need to draw the pie chart manually. How to do this with the help of Canvas or other ways?

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use canvas for drawing piechart in android because 3rd party api will not give you that type of satisfaction as you need.

well, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981996/click-event-on-pie-chart-in-android) will help you in drawing that type of canvas piechart for android.
Hope it's useful to you.

[[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) [piechart](/questions/tagged/piechart) [chart](/questions/tagged/chart) [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas)